# What makes a song "danceable"?

Tags: dancing

**[Music Fans Topic Challenge #2 - Dancing](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/music-fans-topic-challenge-2-dancing)**

---

We recently had [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5868/im-wondering-if-there-is-a-word-for-drum-rhythms-that-make-you-want-to-dance) about the term for danceability in music.  But have there been any scientific studies about what actually makes music danceable?

I would assume it has to do with tempo, time-signature and structure, but are there actual defined parameters?

Comment: There are some theories that dance is what the audience does as a consequence of music, but time and again I encounter musicians who say that dancing music comes from witnessing the people dance.  But I will look into actual dance theory books.  Dance is part of the Fine Arts regimen so there is probably lots to look at there.